# Bug with mine 'AutoImport' function

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, backend

There is my error in console:

> 2022-01-17T08:43:15.669Z] Executed 'AutoImport' (Failed,
> Id=cfafc70c-40f4-4b42-9af5-76ca76daa53d, Duration=652ms)
> [2022-01-17T08:43:15.670Z] System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while
> executing function: AutoImport. TeamsAllocationManager.Integrations:
> An unexpected error occurred calling external API.
> service:FutureDatabase; code:NotFound; message (optional):Not Found.

And there is a code of function:

```
[FunctionName("AutoImport")]
        public async Task AutoImport([TimerTrigger("*/15 * * * * *")] TimerInfo timer, ILogger logger)
        {
            using (logger.BeginScope(new Dictionary<string, object>
            {
                ["AppVersion"] = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version?.ToString() ?? "-",
                ["Action"] = "AutoImport",
            }))
            {
                try
                {
                    logger.LogInformation($"Auto Import action started");

                    var command = new ImportProjectsAndEmployeesCommand();
                    await _dispatcher.DispatchAsync<ImportProjectsAndEmployeesCommand, ImportReportDto>(command);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    LogException(logger, ex);
                    throw;
                }
            }
        }
```

Error triggers in handler by line:

```
ICollection<User>? users = await _futureDatabaseApiClient.GetUsersAsync();
```

Im not sure why it occurs, it happen only in dev, in azure i didnt noticed this error. I had a clue about nugets but idk how to figure out which package is missing ( i tried install few or update some and error still occurs).

Sombody know the solution?

Comment: Hi there and welcome at Stack Overflow! This website is meant as a forum to help developers overcome issue they encounter while trying when trying to get stuff to work. Questions in the form "here's my code, why doesn't it work?" are not what we're aiming at. We would like to see you put in some effort, too. Please refer to [ask] and update your question. Also: the line that supposedly triggers the error isn't even in the code you posted. It's impossible for us to find the issue with the question in its current form.

Comment: To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

The `FutureDatabaseApiClient` you're using is calling an API that doesn't exist. The error message clearly states:

> An unexpected error occurred calling external API. service:FutureDatabase; code:**NotFound**.

This might be because of a (base) URL not set correctly, or it being a relative URL.